# Assign value to a multi key dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Still a rookie in Python. I have a multi-key dict and I am looping through it to assign some new keys/values to it. Here is the code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':[{'A': {'val1': 5}, 'B': {'val1': 1}}, {'C': {'val1': 6}, 'D': {'val1': 3}}, {'E': {'val1': 6}, 'F': {'val1': 1}, 'G': {'val1': 1}}]})
df_dict = df.col2.to_dict()


for index in range(len(df_dict)):
    for key in df_dict[index].keys():
        df_dict[index][key]['val2'] = '10'
        df_dict[index][key]['val3'] = '100'

print(df_dict)
{0: {'A': {'val1': 5, 'val2': '10', 'val3': '100'}, 'B': {'val1': 1, 'val2': '10', 'val3': '100'}}, 1: {'C': {'arv': '10:00', 'val1': 6, 'val2': '10', 'val3': '100'}, 'D': {'val1': 3, 'val2': '10', 'val3': '100'}}, 2: {'E': {'val1': 6, 'val2': '10', 'val3': '100'}, 'F': {'val1': 1, 'val2': '10', 'val3': '100'}, 'G': {'val1': 1, 'val2': '10', 'val3': '100'}}}
```

My question is if there is a faster/intuitive way doing this work?

Comment: Assign directly to the dataframe. Why are you using the dictionary after making a DF?

Comment: @MadPhysicist the df comes with a dict col. How can I assign directly?

Comment: `df_dict = df.col2.to_dict()` is extra steps that don't do what you think they do. Why not `df.col2[...][...] = ...`, or `iloc`